# Best practice for a lot of math behind an ASP.NET request

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, multithreading, math, request

I plan on instantiating objects (classes) to do a lot of math calculations based on a user's input. My gut feeling is that I can load an animated wait-GIF on an output URL (page), then define the new class, set the parameters, start a thread, and then reload the blank page when done. Wouldn't ASP.NET already have things like animated wait GIFs already bundled?   Also, by default, wouldn't GC (garbage collection) be done on the closed object (class) when done?  This way, the ASP server would merely have multiple threads if there were multiple users.  Just some questions, since most of my experience is WinForms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that is right. Do all the processing inside the button_click. A class is being instantiated for you in the page. Asp.net will handle all the threading for simultaneous users.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Quick question: When the Button_click is fired, and calculations start, what I should I do with the users page? -- maybe take them to a blank  .html file with an animated waitgif linked to it, or is there a fast way for ASP to show a wait icon, then load when done.  Basically, at the end of calculations in button_click, I plan on writing to disk an .html file with a .css table of results on it, and then will need that to load for the user to see the css table.

Answer (score -1):

While you haven't mentioned what kind of web-framework you are using, personally i would perform this type of calculation behind an AJAX request.  Use an  and an  control to provide feedback to the user (wait-GIF animation) until the request has completed.  These are features that are already bundled in a standard ASP.NET site.  Do NOT instantiate your own threads in an ASP.NET application.  ASP.NET is already multi-threaded and is able to handle simultaneous requests to your application.  Your sample HTML code might looks something like this:

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
             html code goes here.  somewhere you might have a button which triggers a postback that will trigger the start of your math computations...
             <asp:LinkButton ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click">Start Computations</asp:LinkButton>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

somewhere else on the page you include your updateprogress tag.  You can see that i've associated this tag with the update panel id that is triggering the postback.

```
<asp:UpdateProgress DisplayAfter="100" runat="server" ID="udp" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1">
    <ProgressTemplate>
        put your animated gif here using an <img /> tag
    </ProgressTemplate>    
</asp:UpdateProgress>
```

Use a server control to re-display your computed text back on the page when it's been calculated.

```
     <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                 <asp:Label id="lblResults" runat="server" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and the code behind for your button click

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //do your computations here
   lblResults.Text = "the answer";
   UpdatePanel2.Update();
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: UpdatePanel is a gross abomination that should be avoided as much as possible. And long running processes don't belong in HTTP requests, even asynchronous ones. Instead, an initial request should be made which queues the work to be done in the background, and that request should immediately receive a response. Then the client can even poll the server to see when the work is done, or the server can push out a notification signifying that the work is done.

Comment: Your answer assumes the framework being used is Web Forms - however ASP.NET encompasses far more than that: MVC, Web Pages, Razor Pages, SignalR etc. You should not assume the framework being used, ask for clarification if necessary before answering such a question.

Comment: It is indeed an "ASP.NET Web Application" project, and I have a msgbox popup working correctly inside Button1, which simply acquires text from a TextBox1 on the Default.apsx page.  It sounds like I can just march forward and do all the math inside Button1_click, and let ASP do all the threading?  Therefore, I don't need to (a) instantiate a class, (b) start a thread inside the class's constructor, which calls a method containing the calculations, and let GC take its own course.   Can e.g. 100 users click on Button1 simultaneously, and ASP will handle all the threading?

Comment: @wrtsvkrfm There was no question it's an ASP.NET Web Application. The question was over what the framework was, because there are many within ASP.NET. Since you've mentioned ASPX we can probably assume it's Web Forms, though that's the kind of detail you should put in your question. Anyways, how did you implement this message box? Did you use the MessageBox class?

Comment: No, I was using VB.NET and simply used msgbox("hello world") inside the Button_click.  But I don't plan on using that -- only the calculations.

Comment: I was reading that as long as I have a submit button between <form> and </form>, the result will be loaded on the same page the user is on.  For me, however, at the end of the calculations inside the button_click I want to write the contents of a css table to an .html that the user sees.  So what's the trick to prepare a css table (in an .html file) to auto-reload to the user when the button_click calculations are done?